# Why YouCompleteMe still show syntax warning when I include the correct C++ library?

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

When I include the required library, the "#include.." line doesn't show any warning. But when I use the functions in that library, I find the Vim shows that "..use of undeclared function...". It seems that the library is not correctly included. So I want to know how to figure out this problem?

The screenshots for this question are attached as follows:

[image: Syntax Error Warning]

[image: Setting for .ycm_extra_conf.py file]

Answer (score 1):

Try including it as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  //use <> instead of  ""
```

Also, the "printf" function comes from the "cstdio" library so try implementing that library as well,

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**UPDATED**

The easiest way to fix that problem is;

Include the stdio.h library

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Then, instead of typing;

```
printf('s');
```

you do,

```
printf("s");
```

Now, if you really want to print a character 's', then use,

```
printf("%c", 's');   // Tells the printf function that 's' is a character
```

The final code would look like;

```
#include <stdio.h>      
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("s"); 
    printf("%c", 's');
    return 0;
}
```

Now, your comment was that "cout" does not work. In order for "cout" to work you need to include the iostream library:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Then, you can use "cout" in your code;

```
std::cout << 's';
std::cout << "s";
```

Or you can include "namespace std" and the "iostream" library to avoid using std:: before "cout"

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Thereafter, use cout without std::

```
cout << 's';
cout << "s";
```

The final code would be;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    cout << 's';
    cout << "s";
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to learn more about what is in the iostream library and how to use it I recommend using this site:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Also, for the stdio.h,

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

Comment: It still doesn't work. Actually the "...cout..." line also doesn't work when I include the iostream and using namespace std. So I think it doesn't result from this reason.

Comment: I edited (UPDATED) the answer with step by step solution of your problem.